# How do you make the linewidth of a single line change as a function of x in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Does anyone know how to make the linewidth of a single line change as a function of x in matplotlib? For example, how would you make a line thin for small values of x, and thick for large values of x?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want: where do you want the line to start and end? Is it only a vertical line? Also, what have you tried so far, what are you having issues with?

Comment: The basic idea is that I have an array of x values, and array of y values, and an array of what I want the linewidth to be at each point.  The issue is when you plot a line the linewidth keyword only takes a single number.  I can't find any way to make it take a range of values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically, you need to use a polygon instead of a line.  As a quick example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make the original line...
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = 2 * x
thickness = 0.5 * np.abs(np.sin(x) * np.cos(x))

plt.fill_between(x, y - thickness, y + thickness, color='blue')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or if you want something closer to your description:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make the original line...
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.cos(x)
thickness = 0.01 * x

plt.fill_between(x, y - thickness, y + thickness, color='blue')
plt.show()
```

[image]